# Looking for a package to symbolically manipulate statistical expressions

Tags: descriptive-statistics, software

I'm looking for a package that allows to manipulate statistical expressions symbolically, similar to how one can simplify, expand, factor, etc. with Matlab, Mathematica or SAGE.

Using rules such as
$$ \mathbb{E}[A + B] = \mathbb{E}[A] + \mathbb{E} [B] $$
$$ Var[X] = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^{2}] =  \mathbb[E]{X^{2}} - \mathbb{E}[X]^{2}$$ 
etc.

Does anyone know if such functionality exist?

Comment: Such a package could be written within some symbolics math package such as maple, but if it has been done ...